# SQL Server query returns too many records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables in my SQL Server database.

They are linked together as shown in this picture (lines are connected to right rows in picture)

[image: ER Model]

I have a query which should return all the reparations from `tblreparations` with some information about what is repaired, but instead it returns the reparation 3 times, one time for each laptop that the client (klant in dutch) has assigned to it, while the reparations table (reparaties in dutch) only contains one `laptopID` each row

This is the query:

```
SELECT AankopenReparaties.Id, 
       AankopenReparaties.KlantenId, 
       AankopenReparaties.actietype, 
       AankopenReparaties.voorwerptype, 
       laptopscomputers.merk, 
       laptopscomputers.model, 
       laptopscomputers.info, 
       AankopenReparaties.info, 
       AankopenReparaties.Prijs, 
       AankopenReparaties.lopend 
FROM AankopenReparaties, laptopscomputers 
WHERE (aankopenreparaties.lopend = 'lopend');
```

It returns this

[image: Query results]

and it should be only one row since the reparations table (aankopenreparaties) only contains one row with one `laptopID`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Please help because it should be fixed soon (it's an assignment for school)

Comment: Look up JOIN using an ON clause.  The syntax you are using results in a CROSS JOIN because you aren't specifying how the two tables are related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you are returning too many records is because your query produces cartesian product of both tables. You need to tell the server on how the two tables are related with each other.

```
SELECT  AankopenReparaties.Id,
        AankopenReparaties.KlantenId,
        AankopenReparaties.actietype,
        AankopenReparaties.voorwerptype,
        laptopscomputers.merk,
        laptopscomputers.model,
        laptopscomputers.info,
        AankopenReparaties.info,
        AankopenReparaties.Prijs,
        AankopenReparaties.lopend
FROM    AankopenReparaties
        INNER JOIN laptopscomputers
            ON AankopenReparaties.LaptopID = laptopscomputers.ID -- specify relationship
WHERE   aankopenreparaties.lopend = 'lopend'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

- [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: +1; Probably useful to inform OP about explicit vs implicit `JOIN`

Comment: The 1st link's blog post's author repudiates that very post in its comments. Such Venn-like diagrams are misleading & unhelpful. [Venn Diagram for Natural Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642928/3404097) [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097)