# Joining tables on foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, microsoft-metro

I have the following three tables:

- Product
- Purchase (contains ProductID as foreign key)
- Sale (contain ProductID as foreign key as well)

I want to form query joining these 3 tables where my result is the product name, purchased, and sold.

`Product Name` - (from Products table)

`Purchased` - (Number of occurences in Purchase table according to ProductID)

`Sold` -  (Number of occurences in Sale Table according to ProductID)

Can you please set me on the right track by giving me hints and I'll complete by myself?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: it would be more beneficial to you if you had tried and came to us when you got stuck, but here's a hint: `SQL INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as a hint, you need to use a join of some sort ([join fundamentals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx)).

A possible answer is below:

```
Select p.ProductName, pu.Purchased, s.Sold
From Products p 
INNER JOIN Purchase pu on p.ProductID = pu.ProductID
INNER JOIN Sale s on s.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: That's not nice!!! *Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime*. **You just gave him a fish.** +1 though!!!

Comment: Him and 12k other people. If you fished the answer in some other question, you could flag this one as duplicate, you know.

Answer (score 26):

I'm betting this will get deleted...but hopefully you see this before it does. The following is really helpful in understanding the differences in the SQL JOINS. [image: SQL JOINS]. This answer or Kyle's answers is all you need to solve your question.

Source: [INNER JOIN, LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923616/inner-join-left-right-outer-join)

Comment: If you are going to down vote explain why this is wrong?