# Where to put conditions in Multiple Joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, left-join

Say if I have this query

```
SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.Number, TableA.Name, TableA.HOl, TableB.Contact, TableC.activity
FROM TableA
left JOIN TableB on TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_Id 
left join TableC on TableB.userid = TableC.userid
where TableA.hol = 50 
order By TableA.Id
```

Is it better to but the TableA.Hol in the where or in the ON clause?

I am not sure if it makes a difference, I am trying to determine why it slow.  Maybe it something else with my joins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditions in LEFT JOIN (OUTER JOIN) vs INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977119/conditions-in-left-join-outer-join-vs-inner-join)

Comment: How can we know whether "it is better"? All you give is a query & all you say is you want "multiple joins". Read & act on [mcve]. If your query returns the correct answer then re moving around your where condition: You really need to find out what left join returns--inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. With a series of inner joins you can move conditions between on & where (assuming names are in scope.) But not if there are outer joins since it affects what null-extended rows are returned. Re "slow": That is a different question--for after you get a correct query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select TableA.Id, TableA.Number, TableA.Name, TableA.HOl, TableB.Contact, TableC.activity
from TableA left join
     TableB
     on TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_Id left join
     TableC
on TableB.userid = TableC.userid
where TableA.hol = 50 
order By TableA.Id;
```

A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of what the `on` clause evaluates to.  This means that a condition on the *first* table is effectively ignored in the `on` clause.  Well, not exactly ignored -- the condition is false so the columns from the second table will be `NULL` for those rows.

So, filters on the first table in a `left join` should be in the `where` clause.

Conditions on subsequent tables should be in the `on` clause.  Otherwise, those conditions will turn the outer join into an inner join.

Comment: ok, so right now my query is correct then? Any tips on how to make it faster? It takes a long time to run.

Comment: Also, does the group by always go outside of the joins as well?

Comment: @chobo2 . . . presumably, you need an index on `tableA(hol, id)`, and on the join columns in the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Number, A.Name, A.HOl, B.Contact, C.activity
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B
ON (A.Id = B.TableA_Id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC C
ON (B.userid = C.userid)
AND A.hol = 50
ORDER BY A.Id
```

If you are referencing more than one table you can use an alias which improves readability. But this has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: Index all the predicates in JOIN, WHERE, ORDER BY clauses.
remove unnecessary columns this will help you in query optimization

Comment: Please explain in your post how it answers the question. Here you are moving a test from a where to an on but in what way does this answer the question, which is about *why* & *whether* this should be done. So this is a poor answer. PS Please read the edit help & look at the formatted version below the edit box. Click on 'edited' to see how I edited your post to format code. Edit clarifications/additions seamlessly into your posts, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you are using `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`, use `ON` to specify how the tables are related and use `WHERE` to filter.

In the case of `JOIN`, the it does not matter where you put the filtering; it is for readability that you should follow the above rule.

In the case of `LEFT JOIN`, the results are likely to be different.

If you do

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

you can see what the SQL parser decided to do.  In general, it moves `ON` clauses are to `WHERE`, indicating that it does not matter (to the semantics) which place they are.  But, for `LEFT JOIN`, some things must remain in the `ON`.

Note another thing:

```
FROM a ...
LEFT JOIN b ...
WHERE b.foo = 123
```

effectively throws out the `LEFT`.  The difference between `LEFT` and non-`LEFT` is whether you get rows of `b` filled with `NULLs`.  But `WHERE b.foo = 123` says you definitely do not want such rows.  So, for clarity for the reader, do not say `LEFT`.

So, I agree with your original formulation.  But I also like short aliases for all tables.  *Be sure to qualify all columns -- the reader may not know which table a column is in.*

Your title says "multiple" joins.  I discussed a single `JOIN`; the lecture applies to any number of `JOINs`.