# selecting from 6 tables useing JOIN got duplicated value

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

[image: Tables diagrams here]

her is the mySql to select the students

```
$institute = $_POST['institute'];
$sections = $_POST['sections'];
$division = $_POST['division'];

$getSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT
a.name, a.phase, a.setNumber, a.email, a.sudImage, a.activity, a.id AS stud_id,
b.id, b.ins_name,
c.id, c.sec_name,
d.id, d.div_name,
e.id, e.std_id, e.sub_id, e.absence,
f.id, f.sub_name, f.subHour, f.level
FROM student_basic_info AS a
CROSS JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)
CROSS JOIN ins_sections AS c ON (a.section = c.id)
CROSS JOIN ins_division AS d ON (a.division = d.id)
CROSS JOIN student_absence AS e
CROSS JOIN ins_subjects AS f ON (e.sub_id = f.id)
WHERE a.institute =? AND a.section = ? AND a.division =?
GROUP BY a.id
");

$studSearch = array();
$getSearch->bind_param('iii', $institute, $sections, $division);
if ($getSearch->execute()) {
$results = $getSearch->get_result();
//var_dump($studSearch);
$row_cnt = $results->num_rows;
?>
```

**The Problem is**
the results should have 2 rows effected 
row one come's out right the second come's duplicated

see the var_dump row one

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=17)
      'name' => string 'Yousef' (length=6)
      'phase' => string 'اعدادي' (length=12)
      'setNumber' => int 1234
      'email' => string 'johnef' (length=6)
      'sudImage' => string '' (length=0)
      'activity' => int 0
      'stud_id' => int 2
      'id' => int 3
      'ins_name' => string 'fonon' (length=5)
      'sec_name' => string 'فنون مسرح' (length=17)
      'div_name' => string 'شعبة مرجانية 10' (length=26)
      'std_id' => int 4
      'sub_id' => int 3
      'absence' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sub_name' => string 'فنون تطبيقية' (length=23)
      'subHour' => string '2' (length=1)
      'level' => string 'المستوي الأول' (length=25)
```

see the var_dump row two

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=17)
      'name' => string 'Yousef' (length=6)
      'phase' => string 'اعدادي' (length=12)
      'setNumber' => int 1234
      'email' => string 'johnef' (length=6)
      'sudImage' => string '' (length=0)
      'activity' => int 0
      'stud_id' => int 2
      'id' => int 3
      'ins_name' => string 'fonon' (length=5)
      'sec_name' => string 'فنون مسرح' (length=17)
      'div_name' => string 'شعبة مرجانية 10' (length=26)
      'std_id' => int 4
      'sub_id' => int 3
      'absence' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sub_name' => string 'فنون تطبيقية' (length=23)
      'subHour' => string '2' (length=1)
      'level' => string 'المستوي الأول' (length=25)
  1 => 
    array (size=17)
      'name' => string 'Rida Ali' (length=8)
      'phase' => string 'ابتدائي' (length=14)
      'setNumber' => int 0
      'email' => string 'johnef' (length=6)
      'sudImage' => string '' (length=0)
      'activity' => int 0
      'stud_id' => int 7
      'id' => int 3
      'ins_name' => string 'fonon' (length=5)
      'sec_name' => string 'فنون مسرح' (length=17)
      'div_name' => string 'شعبة مرجانية 10' (length=26)
      'std_id' => int 4
      'sub_id' => int 3
      'absence' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sub_name' => string 'فنون تطبيقية' (length=23)
      'subHour' => string '2' (length=1)
      'level' => string 'المستوي الأول' (length=25)
```

**I try** to put this condition `CROSS JOIN student_absence AS e ON (e.std_id = a.id)` but it come's out with one row only

**try 2 with INNER JOIN**

```
.....<br/>
FROM student_basic_info AS a
INNER JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)<br/>
.....
```

results 
it coming out correct **but** it should come out with 2 rows now it's coming out with one row only.

**try 2 with LEFT JOIN**

```
    SELECT
a.name, a.phase, a.setNumber, a.email, a.sudImage, a.activity, a.id AS stud_id,
b.id, b.ins_name,
c.id, c.sec_name,
d.id, d.div_name,
e.id, e.std_id, e.sub_id, e.absence,
f.id, f.sub_name, f.subHour, f.level
FROM student_basic_info AS a
INNER JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)
INNER JOIN ins_sections AS c ON (a.section = c.id)
INNER JOIN ins_division AS d ON (a.division = d.id)

LEFT JOIN student_absence AS e ON (e.std_id = a.id)
LEFT JOIN ins_subjects AS f ON (f.id = e.sub_id)

WHERE a.institute =? AND a.section = ? AND a.division =?
GROUP BY a.id
```

results 
it coming out correct

Comment: Are you sure that this should be `CROSS JOIN` intead of `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: I try this too and no luck I don't think it makes any different

Comment: There is a HUGE difference between a CROSS and an INNER join. You should read about it here on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759687/cross-join-vs-inner-join-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: I think there is something do with this `CROSS JOIN student_absence AS e`

Comment: Most probably it is this. It should be all INNER JOINs (seeing your problem) and that specific line should be something like `INNER JOIN student_absence AS e ON (e.someColumn = OneOfTheAlreadyMentionedTables.SomeColumnName)`

Comment: @JorgeCampos see my edit

Comment: Then you have now a problem with your data, some table may have two equivalences (for your joins). Is the two rows equals? If so adding just the DISTINCT keyword will solve your problem like `select DISTINCT a.name ...... ` But only if this is just what you need.

Comment: @JorgeCampos attached my tables diagrams to the question

Comment: a link to google drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6fKNygRi_UGSHFlSktmRW9OM1E

Comment: I am very sorry for that here is a free link http://1drv.ms/1MzSy3m it's on oneDrive

Comment: Which two rows are you expecting to be output? Make it really clear what you expect the result to be. If it is your: `see the var_dump row two` Then make it clear that is the result you expect to see from the query. If we provide an answer then we are expected to explain how we got to it so it so you will understand the process.

Comment: @RyanVincent See my edit and +1 for your effort and about your question, I expected the the effected rows to come up.