# Displaying multiple databse files data multiple times. Somewhere I did wrong. Unable to find where. Here is my code

Tags: c#

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = M2\SQL2016; Initial Catalog = inventoryDB; Integrated Security = True");
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select brnDB.catname, catDB.hsncode, brnDB.compname, itemDB.fullname, companyDB.compcode from brnDB cross join  itemDB cross join companyDB cross join catDB where catDB.catname=brnDB.catname and companyDB.compcode=2 order by fullname asc", con);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
 dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

> I run this code, data is coming but multipul times (repeating more
>   than 12 times)

Comment: Did you check your query in MS-SQL ? What is the result? Is it multiple or as you expect?

Comment: @ SMTBCJ15 I checked in SQL. There also same

Comment: what same? multiple ? attach a snapshot of your sql data returned . or > write dataGridView1.DataSource = null instead of dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

Comment: @ SMTBCJ15 I wrote what you told. But same problem.

Comment: Above code have no problem at all. And,it is impossible to trace out your problem until you give a snapshot of you data returned from table in SQL

Comment: @ SMTBCJ15 how to attach a snapshot in comments

Comment: [IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/2rw8i0g.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: @SMTBCJ15 I added snapshot link.

Comment: I have looked at the image which you attached, what is multiple data there now? I didn't found multiple records there

Comment: @ SMTBCJ15 first record it self 3 times came below that record only. Like that all records

Comment: You have problem in your query where one company have ordered multiple products. For this you'll have to look into your query.

Comment: @ SMTBCJ15 there records repeating according to how many companies I am having. Now I am having 3 companies. so one record is adding into all companies so first one plues 3 times more like that it came. I created one more company and checked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to do `cross join` instead of `inner join`?

Check out this question:
[CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759687/cross-join-vs-inner-join-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @ Peter inner join some syntax error came so i used cross join

Comment: @ peter SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@" select 
                                                        brnDB.brname, catDB.catname, itemDB.fullname
                                                        from brnDB inner join catDB inner join itemDB on brnDB.brname=itemDB.brname  ", con);

Comment: @vijay you need to specify what to join on: select brnDB.brname, catDB.catname, itemDB.fullname from brnDB inner join catDB on brnDB.catDBId = catDB.Id  or something similar. Checkout this link for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp