# MySQL Left Outer Join with Absence Condition

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

## Overview

I'm simplifying the description of my application to make the query clearer.  The application stores saved `phrases`.  These phrases are each assigned a `category`.  The phrases can be `posted` by `users`.  An English description of my query:

> I need to pass a `category` and `user` into the `prepared statement`. 
>   The result will include only `phrases` with the `category` passed as an argument.  From the `phrases` of this `category`, only `phrases` will be returned where there does not exist any posted instances of this `phrase`
>   for the `user` argument with the `timePosted` field in the last two weeks.

## Minimal Schema

#### savedPhrase

- phraseIdentifier - INT UNSIGNED
- textContent - VARCHAR
- associatedCategory - VARCHAR
- ___primary key is phraseIdentifier

#### postedPhrase

- savedPhrase - INT UNSIGNED - foreign key references savedPhrase(phraseIdentifier)
- username - VARCHAR
- timeReposted - TIMESTAMP
- ___primary key is combination of all listed fields

## Current Best Attempt with Behavior

I'm self-taught/learning MySQL and believe I struggle with `joins`.  I think I should be using at least one `left outer join` as seen in the graphic below.  The left table will be `savedPhrase` and the right will be `postedPhrase`.

[image: Left Outer Join]

```
SELECT * FROM savedPhrase S 
LEFT JOIN postedPhrase P
ON (S.phraseIdentifier = P.savedPhrase AND P.username = ?)
WHERE
(P.savedPhrase IS NULL OR P.timeReposted < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 day)) AND
S.associatedCategory = ?
```

The query above ALMOST works.  However, once a single `postedPhrase` row exists at least two weeks ago, it will return the joined `savedPhrase`, even if one has been posted on the same account with the same identifier less than two weeks ago.

## Further Discussion

The place where I'm having difficulty is the "absence condition".  This is where a `savedPhrase` must not exist within the last two weeks.  In the previous paragraph I explained how the absence is not functioning because the `postedPhrase`s are being returned based on their own independent `timeReposted`.  It seems I should be adding the absence condition to the right circle of the left outer join.  Simplification of when to apply the conditions to the `ON` versus the `WHERE` would be very helpful.

I've worked at fixing this problem for a while and would appreciate any direction.  Please let me know if I can include any other information.

Comment: Most of those Venn diagram presentations are not illustrating what they claim to be. Left/right join returns what inner join returns plus unmatched left/right rows extended by nulls. Where happens after all joins. For a Venn diagram, the rows of inner join are in the intersection and the left/right circle is left/right join rows. So unmatched rows extended by nulls are in the left & right lobes. Full join is both circles. Re joins see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097) and its links. Re querying see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097).

Comment: PS Your Venn diagram illustrates SQL EXCEPT aka DIFFERENCE, for two tables that have the same set of columns. Left/right circles are the input tables, left lobe the result. But left outer join is *part* of an *idiom* for expressing that. (You can also use NOT IN & NOT EXISTS. Google stackoverflow.) But the diagram is only obscurely related to the left join. And the code is even more obscurely related.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks - I really appreciate all of the information!  I will take some time to thoroughly read all of it before making any additional comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to to use *JOIN* to archive the result that you want.
You could write the query base on the English description of the query which described on your question.

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM   savedPhrase S 
WHERE  S.associatedCategory = ? 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   postedPhrase P 
                       WHERE  P.username = ? 
                              AND S.phraseIdentifier = P.savedPhrase 
                              AND P.timeReposted >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), 
                                                    INTERVAL 14 day))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!  I completely forgot about the NOT EXISTS keyword combination.  I don't need to use a join, since I don't need any information from the `postedPhrase` table, right?