# Count between multiple tables

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have these 3 tables with the following structures:

**Products**

```
product_id | category_id | product_name
```

**Customers**

```
customer_id | customer_name
```

**Orders**

```
order_id | customer_id | product_id
```

I need to write a SQL query that will print the top customers regarding the number of categories they have bought products from (the best customer is the one that has bought from the most categories).

Can anyone show me how to do that?

I tried like this, but I get the following error "not a GROUP BY expression":

```
select 
    (select customer_name 
     from customers 
     where customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id) as name,    
    (select count(category_id) 
     from products 
     where products.product_id = orders.product_id)
from 
    orders
group by 
    customer_id
order by 
    count(customer_id) desc;
```

I managed to make the top regarding how many products the customers bought. The solution I used is:

```
select 
    (select customer_name from customers 
     where customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id) as name,   
    count(product_id) as "number of ordered products"
from 
    orders
group by 
    customer_id
order by 
    count(product_id) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested queries for this? Sheesh...
Just join them already.
And then order by the unique categories

```
SELECT c.customer_name
, COUNT(DISTINCT p.category_id) AS TotalOrderedCategories
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Customers c ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN Products p ON p.product_id = o.product_id
GROUP BY c.customer_name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT p.category_id) DESC
```

Then depending on your RDBMS flavor, add a TOP or a LIMIT.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!
Could you please explain to me how INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN work?

Comment: @Athena Look at the picture in this old answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583444/4003419

Comment: Basically, by using LEFT joins it'll also count for orders without a customer or without product.