# Predict the number of rows in output

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, self-join

I have below table:

| col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |

what will be the count of rows after joining the table in col_a and col_b - left, right and inner?
I want to understand how SQL join works.

Comment: You can only join two tables. What is the second one?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I want to join the table with itself on col_a and col_b.

Comment: _I want to understand how SQL join works_: It is best explained here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/ with venn diagrams

Comment: Explained in [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/4003419).  Btw, both columns in your question have duplicates. In reality, most joins are between many-to-one relationships. F.e. a foreign key to a primary key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: @LukStorms the link you provided just cleared my doubts. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please click to agree this is a duplicate. Also please research before considering posting a question. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

There's more than joins in Sql

> ```
> create table test (col_a int, col_b int);
> insert into test values (1,1),(2,3),(3,2),(4,0);
> ```

> ```
> select * from test order by 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     3
>     3 |     2
>     4 |     0
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- [inner] join: only when a = b
> --
> select a.col_a, b.col_b
> from test a
> join test b 
>   on b.col_b = a.col_a
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     2
>     3 |     3
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- left [outer] join: all of left side a
> --
> select a.col_a, b.col_b
> from test a
> left join test b 
>   on b.col_b = a.col_a
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     2
>     3 |     3
>     4 |  null
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- right [outer] join, all of right side b
> --
> select a.col_a, b.col_b
> from test a
> right join test b 
>   on b.col_b = a.col_a
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>  null |     0
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     2
>     3 |     3
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- full [outer] join: all of left a and all of right b
> --
> select a.col_a, b.col_b
> from test a
> full join test b 
>   on b.col_b = a.col_a
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>  null |     0
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     2
>     3 |     3
>     4 |  null
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- natural join: an inner join, but automatic on the same column names
> --
> select a.col_a, b.col_b
> from test a
> natural join test b
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     3
>     3 |     2
>     4 |     0
> ```

> ```
> --
> --  some join with a "using" instead of "on" 
> --
> select a.col_a, b.col_b
> from test a
> inner join test b using (col_a)
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     3
>     3 |     2
>     4 |     0
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- cross join: a * b (cartesian product)
> --
> select a.col_a, b.col_b
> from test a
> cross join test b
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     1 |     3
>     1 |     2
>     1 |     0
>     2 |     1
>     2 |     3
>     2 |     2
>     2 |     0
>     3 |     1
>     3 |     3
>     3 |     2
>     3 |     0
>     4 |     1
>     4 |     3
>     4 |     2
>     4 |     0
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- lateral join: 
> --
> select a.col_a, lat_b.col_b
> from test a
> cross join lateral (
>   select b.col_b, count(*) as total
>   from test b 
>   where b.col_b = a.col_a
>   group by b.col_b
> ) lat_b
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     2
>     3 |     3
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- correlated sub-query
> --
> select 
>   a.col_a, 
>   (select max(col_b) from test b where a.col_a = b.col_b) as col_b
> from test a
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     2
>     3 |     3
>     4 |  null
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- where b in a
> --
> select a.col_a
> from test a
> where col_a in (select distinct col_b from test b)
> ```
>
> ```
> | col_a |
> | ----: |
> |     1 |
> |     2 |
> |     3 |
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- where tupple in opposite tupple
> --
> select col_a, col_b
> from test a
> where (col_a, col_b) in (select col_b, col_a from test b)
> ```
>
> ```
> col_a | col_b
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     1
>     2 |     3
>     3 |     2
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- where b exists in a
> --
> select a.col_a
> from test a
> where exists (
>   select 1
>   from test b 
>   where b.col_b = a.col_a
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> | col_a |
> | ----: |
> |     1 |
> |     2 |
> |     3 |
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- union all: stack a and b
> --
> select col_a as col_ab from test a
> union all
> select col_b from test b
> ```
>
> ```
> | col_ab |
> | -----: |
> |      1 |
> |      2 |
> |      3 |
> |      4 |
> |      1 |
> |      3 |
> |      2 |
> |      0 |
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- union: stack a and b, but discard duplicates
> --
> select col_a as col_ab from test a
> union
> select col_b from test b
> ```
>
> ```
> | col_ab |
> | -----: |
> |      2 |
> |      4 |
> |      1 |
> |      3 |
> |      0 |
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- intersect: only when the value is in both
> --
> select col_a as col_ab from test a
> intersect
> select col_b from test b
> ```
>
> ```
> | col_ab |
> | -----: |
> |      3 |
> |      2 |
> |      1 |
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- except: a minus b
> --
> select col_a as col_ab from test a
> except
> select col_b from test b
> ```
>
> ```
> | col_ab |
> | -----: |
> |      4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e0b1712bb1d7b5ccc9da98c427d961aa)*