# How to do cross join without cross in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables, hotel and interests. I'd like to find the distance between each hotel and each interests. I tried using CROSS JOIN but my boss told me to not use cross join. Is there any other way? Implicit join and  ON 1=1 is not allowed either. I was told to use join and brackets but I don't understand how is it possible to perform a cross join without using cross join. 
I'm using oracle sql by the way

Comment: In some versions of SQL (e.g. MySQL), doing an _inner_ join without an `ON` condition defaults to being a cross join.  This isn't the case with Oracle though, and an inner join without `ON` will error out.  In practice, your bigger problem here is probably going to be finding a way to compute those distances.

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention. We have a function that calculates distance between coordinates

Comment: How that function will be useful in joins?

Comment: *" I tried using CROSS JOIN but my boss told me to not use cross join"* So what is the point of this? There's no apparent value from implementing a cross join without using CROSS JOIN notation other than confusing the other poor blighters who have to work with your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759687/cross-join-vs-inner-join-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: What does "don't use cross join" mean? We can't tell you an answer until you clarify this. *Every* join (explicit/keyword/`JOIN` or implicit/comma/`,`) does a cross join, but then we only keep some of the rows per `ON`, `WHERE`, etc & the DBMS optimizes the implementation. PS Please explain the exact task you are to do. [mre] PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: After you find out from your boss what they meant by whatever they said that you report here as "don't use cross join" & "use join and brackets" please let us know. That hopefully won't leave any question to ask or answer, but what you say here about what your boss said just is not clear. PS Presumably a reasonable calculation involves recursively calculating longer distances only from relevant slightly shorter distances & also presumably it is in comparison with that that cross join is undesirable.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After searching around I found that you can use < and > in ON. So I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON (a.x<>b.x OR a.x=b.x)
```

And it seems to work just like a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: This will filter out `null` values in `a.x` or `b.x`: [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=443c3319ea8319eaf669b1034d1b0acc)

Answer (score 5):

Well, if both tables have no column in common, you can do a `NATURAL JOIN`: it will generate a cartesian product (also called `CROSS JOIN`):

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1 natural join table2 t2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=88458c4c9c997d06298f28ea74c95535)**:

```
with 
    a as (select 1 as ida from dual union all select 2 from dual),
    b as (select 3 as idb from dual union all select 4 from dual)
select a.*, b.* from a natural join b
```

```
IDA | IDB
--: | --:
  1 |   3
  1 |   4
  2 |   3
  2 |   4
```

---

**Other options** (but apparently you are not allowed to use them):

Explicit join on 1=1

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on 1 = 1
```

Implicit join:

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2
```

Comment: Your natural join option [does not seem to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e356d024ee7f40625ec64d28e463a23) on Oracle.

Comment: It works with two different tables though (see the link in my answer). With a self-join, it [seems to work with this syntax](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c97e86ac0449511fe86d2548aaec1159)

Comment: Fair enough +1, in any case your other two options seem good.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any extra syntax to carry out a cross join using Oracle sql.

Just listing the tables and not giving a join condition will give you the cartesian product that you're after

`select table1.*, table2.*
 from table1, table2`