# I want to join the two table according to below

Tags: sql-server

table1

```
no  name 
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
```

table2

```
date
1/1/19
2/2/19
```

result will be

```
no  name  date
1   aaa   1/1/19
2   bbb   1/1/19
3   ccc   1/1/19
1   aaa   2/2/19
2   bbb   2/2/19
3   ccc   2/2/19
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: use `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: You need  to show some code for what you have attempted so that we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759687/cross-join-vs-inner-join-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2):

TRY `FULL JOIN`

```
SELECT no, namem, date FROM 
TABLE1 FULL JOIN table2 ON 1 = 1
```

Try `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT no, namem, date  FROM TABLE1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf20b533a108cf6cf897084cae2e0a38)**

Comment: A join with an always true condition is a cross join. instead of `full join... on...` simply use `cross join`.

Comment: @VigneshKumarA I would not advise the usage of * in the select clause. It's unreliable. What if a password field is added to one of the tables with sensitive information?

Comment: @LajosArpad (y) (y) (y)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bad501/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Table1(num int,name varchar(max))
create table Table2(dates date)
insert into Table1(num,name)values(1,'aaa')
insert into Table1(num,name)values(2,'bbb')
insert into Table1(num,name)values(3,'ccc')
insert into Table2(dates)values('2019-01-01')
insert into Table2(dates)values('2019-02-02')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT num,name,dates
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY Table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bad501/3/0)**:

```
| num | name |      dates |
|-----|------|------------|
|   1 |  aaa | 2019-01-01 |
|   2 |  bbb | 2019-01-01 |
|   3 |  ccc | 2019-01-01 |
|   1 |  aaa | 2019-02-02 |
|   2 |  bbb | 2019-02-02 |
|   3 |  ccc | 2019-02-02 |
```