# How to make a list between two table with all possible combination?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tablee.

```
Table A
  ID
A001
A002
A003

Table B
 COUNTRY
      UK
     USA
 GERMANY
   CHINA
```

I'd like to list all posible combination from each `ID` and each `CONTRY`

My expected result should be:

```
A001        UK
A001       USA
A001   GERMANY
A001     CHINA
A002        UK
A002       USA
A002   GERMANY
A002     CHINA
A003        UK
A003       USA
A003   GERMANY
A003     CHINA
```

Comment: `SELECT A.id, B.country
FROM A
CROSS JOIN B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`Cross Join`** to resolve it, Read @Sarath Avanavu's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21794288/9071943) link to have a better understanding.

```
SELECT a.ID, b.COUNTRY
FROM TABLE a
Cross Join TABLE b
```

Answer (score 1):

this is just `cross join`.

```
select * from tableA t1
cross join tableB
order by t1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `CROSS JOIN` here.  Note for completeness that in MySQL, an inner join without any join criteria behaves like a cross join.  So, we could actually try:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.COUNTRY
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ORDER BY a.ID, b.COUNTRY;
```