# SELECT FROM from multiple tables vs JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, select

Beginner Q. Learning SQL and was doing some online training exercises and came across this solution to create a summary from two tables:

```
SELECT salesman.name AS "Salesman",
customer.cust_name, customer.city 
FROM salesman,customer 
WHERE salesman.city=customer.city;
```

I find this confusing because I would have expected to do a JOIN when pulling from two different tables. My Udemy training never gave examples of FROM statements for multiple tables at the same time : )

Is this an alternate way of doing a basic JOIN? Or is there some reason JOIN does something this can't?

Thanks

Comment: Implicit joins were replaced with explicit join syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL standards. Nearly 30 years later, the ANSI-89 implicit syntax is still oddly being used, and more oddly being taught, but most practitioners caution against using it. There's a lot of good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).

Comment: The comma is just an archaic way of writing the `JOIN`.  Best to forget you ever saw it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: Comma is cross join with lower precedence than keyword joins. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `join` as follow, this is called `explicit join`, and you should always try to use this as it provides more readability in query.

```
SELECT 
  s.name as Salesman,
  c.cust_name, 
  c.city 
FROM salesman s
join customer c
on s.city=c.city;
```

when you use multiple table with `where` statement then it is called `implicit join` as you have used in your query. performance wise both should be the same.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with the concept of explicit vs implicit joins. Sounds like it's ok (and perhaps better for readability) to just stick to explicit joins in general.