# SQL query only returns values for the first JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table named `Books` and a temp table named `AccessRights` with the following rows:

```
create table Books
(
  BookID int,
  Title varchar(150),
  PurchaseDate date,
  Bookstore varchar(150),
  City varchar(150)
);

INSERT INTO Books VALUES (1, 'Cujo', '2022-02-01', 'Central1', 'New York');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (2, 'The Hotel New Hampshire', '2022-01-08', 'Central2', 'Las Vegas');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (3, 'Gorky Park', '2022-05-19', 'Central2', 'New York');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (4, 'Red Dragon', '2022-03-11', 'Central1', 'Las Vegas');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (5, 'Chronicle of a Death Foretold', '2022-01-29', 'Central3', 'New York');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (6, 'The Lord God Made Them All', '2022-04-04', 'Central2', 'New York');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (7, 'A Light in the Attic', '2022-03-24', 'Central3', 'Las Vegas');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (8, 'God Emperor of Dune', '2022-06-05', 'Central1', 'Las Vegas');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (9, 'Tar Baby', '2022-01-15', 'Central1', 'New York');
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (10, ' Jumanji', '2022-02-13', 'Central2', 'New York');

CREATE TABLE #AccessRights
    (
        val varchar(50)NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO #AccessRights VALUES('Central1');
INSERT INTO #AccessRights VALUES('New York');
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4bfaf9e/2).

When I run the script:

```
SELECT * FROM Books t1 
JOIN #AccessRights t2 ON t1.City  = t2.val
JOIN #AccessRights t3 ON t1.Bookstore  = t3.val;
```

It returns the values only for the first JOIN. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the query appears to be working correctly for what's written; it returns rows where the column `City` and `Bookstore` both appear in the table `#AccessRights`. In your sample data, that's only 2 rows, `BookID`s `1` and `9`. If it was ignoring the 2nd join, you would get 6 rows, not 2.

Comment: Obligatory note, as well, that SQL server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for **3 years**; it is long past time you got that upgrade path finalised.

Comment: It should return all the rows from Books where it finds 'Central1' and 'New York' in City OR Bookstore columns.

Comment: You don't have an effective `OR` you have an effective **`AND`**. If you want an `OR`, why not use one `JOIN` and an `OR`, or just use an `IN`?

Comment: I know it may seem nitpicky, but the the words matter because they drive what you translate to code. You will never find a row that has 'Central1' **AND** 'New York' in City. Work on reframing your requirement and that will help as you build out your code.

Comment: @Larnu, it has to be a temp table.

Comment: @Isaac, yes, bad choice of column name.

Comment: *"it has to be a temp table."* I'm not sure of your point, @milo2011 ? Why do you believe you can't use an `IN` or `OR` in a `JOIN` to a temporary table?

Comment: Perhaps any confusion would be cleared up if you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73167123/edit) your question to include your expected results.

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT * FROM Books t1 JOIN #AccessRights t2 ON t2.val IN (t1.Bookstore, t1.City);` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4bfaf9e/8

Comment: @Charlieface is spot on. An equivalent and perhaps easier query to understand would be `SELECT * FROM Books t1 JOIN #AccessRights t2 ON t1.City  = t2.val OR t1.Bookstore  = t2.val`

Comment: [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097) When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [mre] PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can just use a single join with `IN` or `OR`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Books t1
JOIN #AccessRights t2 ON t2.val IN (t1.Bookstore, t1.City);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4bfaf9e/8)