# How to avoid left join to return increased number of records than actual

Tags: sql, hive, left-join, impala

I am performing left join and it's giving me increased number of records.

table 1 has 29 records

table 2 has 2 records

after left join I am getting 31 records instead of 29.

How can I get 29 records

table 1 has 29 records
table 2 has 2 records

output is giving me 31 records using left join

Here is the query.

table1.a1
table1.a2,
table1.a3,
table1.a4,
table2.b1,
table2.b2,
table2.b3,

case when table1.a1 is not null then round(table1.a1,2),
table2.b1 is not null then round(table2.b1,2) else 0 end as amount

from transaction table1
left join account table2

on table1.a1=table2.b1
where table1.external_status in ('A','F')

I am expecting 29 records from table1

Comment: You have duplicates because one row from left table has many corresponding rows on right table. You can make your on condition more precise or drop duplicates after join

Comment: It's your data, you have to decide which rows to return. A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Comment: [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097) 
[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091641/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deduplicate data from tabel2 before joining using a CTE or subquery.

I used your example SQL and modified using a subquery. You can use distinct as well.

```
table1.a1 table1.a2, table1.a3, table1.a4, table2.b1, table2.b2, table2.b3,
case when table1.a1 is not null then round(table1.a1,2), table2.b1 is not null then round(table2.b1,2) else 0 end as amount
from transaction table1 left join 
(select b1,b2,b3, row_number() over(partition by b1 order by b2,b3) as rownum from account) table2
on table1.a1=table2.b1 and table2.rownum=1 where table1.external_status in ('A','F')
```

row_number() will assign number to each row for b1 data like 1,2,3 if there are dups. Now when you do rownum=1, you eliminate duplicates.