# Understanding the similarity between INNER JOIN and CROSS JOIN in MySQL without conditions

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, cross-join

I recently experimented with MySQL queries involving `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN`, both without any specified conditions. Surprisingly, both queries produced the same result for my dataset.

```sql
SELECT * FROM untitled_table INNER JOIN untitled_table2;
SELECT * FROM untitled_table CROSS JOIN untitled_table2;
```

I observed that both `CROSS JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` can be executed without any conditions, and they still yield identical results. Even more intriguingly, MySQL Workbench does not throw any errors when I run `INNER JOIN` without a condition or `CROSS JOIN` with a condition.

Is there any fundamental difference between these two join types when used without conditions?

If there's no distinction, why does MySQL have two keywords for what seems to be the same operation?

Moreover, when I applied conditions to both `CROSS JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`, they still produced matching results.

Why do these seemingly different join types behave similarly in this scenario?

Comment: 'In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other)....' , 'INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product ...' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: @P.Salmon There is one difference between comma and explicit join which is NOT described in the documentation. The precedence - comma have less priority then explicit join. I.e. `a join b join с on a.x=c.y` is correct whereas `a, b join c on a.x=c.y` will fail with 'unknown column a.x'.

Comment: Please: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Comment: @Akina The precedence is described in the documentation.

Comment: Clearly these will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/3404097)

Comment: [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned, in MySQL an inner join with no `ON` conditions behaves identically to a cross join.  It is simply a syntax quirk within MySQL and not much more than this.  It should be noted that in most other databases (e.g. Postgres), an inner join without join criteria results in a syntax compilation error and will not run.

As to *which* version you should use in MySQL, I would opine that you should use `CROSS JOIN`, because it makes it explicit and clear what your intentions are.  Using `INNER JOIN` without criteria, as you have probably seen yourself, might be confusing to someone who is not fluent in MySQL.